# OR condition for running function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have button (".moreAlertsBtn") that run function when user click on it
I would like to run the same function if user click on another button that contain the id "#alertsBtn"

how do I add OR condition?

```
$(document).on('click','.moreAlertsBtn',function() { }
```

also - inside the function, can i add contision if user click on the first button and another if he click on the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just separate them using `comma(,)` like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.moreAlertsBtn, #alertsBtn',function() { });
```

> can i add condition if user click on the first button and another if
>   he click on the second?

```
$(document)
  .on('click','.moreAlertsBtn, #alertsBtn',function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('moreAlertsBtn')) {
      //.moreAlertsBtn clicked

    } else {
       //#alertsBtn clicked
    }
 });
```

Comment: thanks. i edit the question. can you please refer to the second question?

Answer (score 1):

> how do I add OR condition?

You can use the comma, which in CSS is "or" (but keep reading):

```
$(document).on('click','.moreAlertsBtn, #alertsBtn',function() { });
```

**But**:

> also - inside the function, can i add contision if user click on the first button and another if he click on the second?

If you're going to do that, then it makes more sense to use separate handlers:

```
$(document).on('click','.moreAlertsBtn',function() { });
$(document).on('click','#alertsBtn',function() { });
```

But answering the question, yes, you can tell like this:

```
if (this.id === "alertsBtn") {
    // It's #alertsBtn
} else {
    // Must be .moreAlertsBtn
}
```

E.g.:

```
$(document).on('click','.moreAlertsBtn, #alertsBtn',function() {
    if (this.id === "alertsBtn") {
        // It's #alertsBtn
    } else {
        // Must be .moreAlertsBtn
    }
});
```

That works because jQuery will call your handler with `this` referring to the DOM element you "hooked" the event on (even when you're actually doing delegation, as you are in your examples).

Answer (score 1):

You can use comma in-between selectors as follows :

```
$(document).on('click','.moreAlertsBtn,#alertsBtn',function() { }
```

Comment: Thanks @Beginner..:)!